# Sending SMS from Contacts for Multiple Contacts Fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Im trying to acheive the same results as: [Sending SMS from Contacts Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752478/sending-sms-from-contacts-fails)

- Sending an SMS or "App Invite" to contact(s).

The solution to this problem works, but it only allows you to send an SMS to one person at a time. **What I want to do is send an SMS to multiple contacts at one time.** Forgive me if this is fairly easy. I've been up for the past 14 hours programming and most things aren't making sense to me right now.

Heres my code:

```
 //MARK : VARIABLES
let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
let messageViewController = MFMessageComposeViewController()


//MARK : VIEW DID LOAD
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //-- set delegates equal to self
    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
    messageViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self
}

//MARK : MFMESSAGECOMPOSE & CNCONTACTPICKERDELEGATE

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
    //-- select contacts and present message compose view controller
    contacts.forEach { (contact) in
        for data in contact.phoneNumbers {
            let phoneNo = data.value

            //-- configure message view controller
            messageViewController.recipients = [phoneNo]
            messageViewController.body = "Testing Testing"

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.present(self.messageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
}

func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {
    print("cancelled")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loop you are attempting to display an `MFMessageComposeViewController` for each recipient.  This won't work as it will attempt to present multiple view controllers concurrently.

You can present a single `MFMessageComposeViewController` that has all of the recipients specified:

```
var recipients = [String]()
contacts.forEach { (contact) in
    for data in contact.phoneNumbers {
        let phoneNo = data.value
        recipients.append(phoneNo.stringValue)
    }
}

//-- configure message view controller
messageViewController.recipients = recipients
messageViewController.body = "Testing Testing"

self.present(self.messageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error whenever I try to append the phoneNo variable to the recipents array: Cannot convert value of type 'CNPhoneNumber' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: I just took the string value of it by putting in .stringValue

Comment: Thanks alot for your help bro

Comment: Sorry, just saw your other question; I didn't notice your outer loop. I have updated my answer